# p5 Resizing canvas issue; resizeCanvas is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm trying to resize my canvas to the page size and when using P5 and Matter.js and trying to call the resizeCanvas() function from P5 to set canvas width and Height it is telling me resizeCanvas() is not defined I'm unsure why this is happening.

I also Can't figure out how to get code blocks on here to work so here's a [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/iragoyuvor.js) of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resizeCanvas` and other `p5` functions are only available after the setup() function runs. My guess is that the page attempts to `resize` or `orientationchange` before setup() is run. Put:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeGame(), doCanvasResize(), false);
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeGame(), doCanvasResize(), false);
```

inside your `setup` function.

Comment: Thanks this resolved my issue. Only problem now is scaling the objects position accordingly.